# Push back to the another array inside map function in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to do some Calculation inside array, I want to push back to array after iteration.

```
let dataValue = [90, 150, 180, 200, 230, 270]

dataValue.map((data) => {
  let ValueAs = angleToVaue(data); //calculations I do I get some output like this  example: 1000, 3500, 7000, 6000

  //I want to put back to array 
  let arraValue =[];
  arraValue.push(...ValueAs);

  console.log(...ValueAs); // error: valueAs is not iterable
});
```

Comment: It's a typo. `ValueAs` is not `valueAs`. Unrelated: Don't use `map` for this. Use `forEach`.

Comment: Do you want to change the numbers inside dataValue or is it enough to have a new array with the updated dataValues?

Comment: What is `angleToVaue`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide the code of `angleToVaue`? And if it returns a single number, a number isn't an iterable so why do you think you can use `...`?

Comment: `const newData = dataValue.map(angleToValue)` is actually what you want ^^

Comment: Hi, @RickardElimää, new array with updated dataValues

Comment: Then @moonwave99 has the correct answer.

Comment: Hi, Jabba "angleToValue" is big function, if dataValue can be pushed to array inside map function that will be lot helpful, I am not how to push the values to array

Comment: I didn't ask for the full code. I asked for a [mcve]. Currently, it's unclear whether `angleToVaue` returns an iterable or not. But @moonwave99's comment is probably the correct answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess my answer is what you want to achieve. You have typos in your code and wrong logics

```js
let dataValue = [90, 150, 180, 200, 230, 270]

let angleToVaue = (value) => {
  return value/360
}

let arraValue = [];

dataValue.map((data) => {
let valueAs = angleToVaue(data);
arraValue.push(valueAs);
console.log(valueAs);
console.log('I am the array', arraValue)
});
```